# 1-D Fourier Transform Of A 2-D Image But At An Arbitrary Orientation

Tags: image-processing, fft, fourier-transform

If one has a 2-D array and would like to take the 1-D Fourier transform along a direction $\theta$ degrees off the horizontal, is there a better/faster way to do this rather than rotating the image by $-\theta$ degrees, taking the 1-D FT across the columns, and then rotating the result back by $\theta$ degrees?

Comment: Well 2DFFT(rotated(image)) = rotated(2DFFT(image)), right?  So I doubt there's any shortcut for 1DFFT.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the 1D IFFT using a pseudo-polar grid. Fig. 2 in this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.7390&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows an example of such grid.

Possible choices for the angle $\theta$ are going to be limited. but the transform will be free from interpolation artifacts introduced by the rotation algorithm.

Comment: I'm not worried about artifacts since I can use high quality filters in the resampling. It's more about efficiency. Also, $\theta$ really needs to be given to several decimal places, so a psuedo-polar FFT is not a solution.